# How does one jump to a particular offset more than once?

Tags: audio, offset, openal

Imagine this function:

```
void SoundManager::playSource(ALuint sourceID, float offset)
{
    alSourceStop(sourceID);

    ALint iTotal = 0;
    ALint iCurrent = 0;
    ALint uiBuffer = 0;
    alGetSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, &uiBuffer);
    alGetBufferi(uiBuffer, AL_SIZE, &iTotal);
    iCurrent = iTotal * offset;

    alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BYTE_OFFSET, iCurrent);
    alSourcePlay(sourceID);
}
```

The idea is calling `playSource(x, 0.5f)` would jump to (roughly) halfway through the buffer, etc.

It works fine the first time I call it, but if I call it again on the same source (whether that source is playing or not) it begins playing as though I'd called it with offset 0.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved!

Even though the API claims that setting the offsets works on sources in any state, the problem was I should have been calling `alSourceRewind` instead of `alSourceStop` at the start.

It seems setting offsets only works on sources in the `AL_INITIAL` state.

Answer (score 1):

you can play the audio file first,then call `setOffset` like this,don't need to call `alSourcePlay`:

```
- (BOOL)setOffset:(float)offset
{
  ALint iTotal = 0;
  ALint iCurrent = 0;
  ALint uiBuffer = 0;
  alGetSourcei(_sourceID, AL_BUFFER, &uiBuffer);
  alGetBufferi(uiBuffer, AL_SIZE, &iTotal);
  iCurrent = iTotal * offset;
  alSourcei(_sourceID, AL_BYTE_OFFSET, iCurrent);
  return ((_error = alGetError()) != AL_NO_ERROR);
}
```